# Jquery .live passes parameter twice in request

Tags: php, jquery, prettyphoto

I am creating simple login screen which will accept username & password on click of submit button.I tried using .click but its not working at all so i am using .live but its passes same parameter twice in request.

```
$("#loginsubmit").live('click', function (e) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'auth_check.php',
         data: $(loginForm1).serialize(),
         type: 'POST',
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
             if (result == 'success') {}
         },
         error: function (result) {}
     });
     e.preventDefault();
     $.prettyPhoto.close();
     return false;
 });
```

This is what i am getting in request

> pusername=&ppassword=&pusername=abc&ppassword=abc

I am using jquery first time and there is something called pretty photo used in my template.
I guess this pretty photo might be causing issues.

LoginForm1 looks like as follows :

```
<div class="login_register_stuff hide"><!-- Login/Register Modal forms - hidded by default to be opened through modal -->
    <div id="login_panel">
        <div class="inner-container login-panel">
            <h3 class="m_title">SIGN IN YOUR ACCOUNT TO HAVE ACCESS TO DIFFERENT FEATURES</h3>
            <form  name="loginForm1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
                <a href="#" class="create_account" onclick="ppOpen('#register_panel', '280');">CREATE ACCOUNT</a>
                <input type="text" name="pusername" class="inputbox" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password"  name="ppassword" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit"  id="loginsubmit" name="loginsubmit"   value="LOG IN" />
            </form>
            <div class="links"><a href="#" onclick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR USERNAME?</a> / <a href="#" onclick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</a></div>
        </div>
```

prettyphoto section snippet

```
enter  <!-- prettyphoto scripts & styles -->
```

```
function ppOpen(panel, width){
    jQuery.prettyPhoto.close();
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto({social_tools: false, deeplinking: false, show_title: false, default_width: width, theme:'pp_kalypso'});
        jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(panel);
    }, 300);
} // function to open different panel within the panel

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto'], .prettyphoto_link").prettyPhoto({theme:'pp_kalypso',social_tools:false, deeplinking:false});
    jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'pp_kalypso'});
    jQuery("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto[login_panel]']").prettyPhoto({theme:'pp_kalypso', default_width:800, social_tools:false, deeplinking:false});


    jQuery(".prettyPhoto_transparent").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto({social_tools: false, deeplinking: false, show_title: false, default_width: 980, theme:'pp_kalypso transparent', opacity: 0.95});
        jQuery.prettyPhoto.open($(this).attr('href'),'','');
    });

});
```

here

could you please help me to find out the issue.

Comment: at least use .on - .live is deprecated. What does the form look like and what does it look like in chrome's inspect element?

Comment: what is `loginForm1` look like in your code?

Comment: `e` in your code is `undefined`. Your click handler should accept the event object then you can use it.

Comment: @BlackSheep: it will, but the code didn't even reach the preventDefault, it's ajax request not complete yet

Comment: I think you put the name attribute on the labels with same name as input

Comment: @user2002495 It's an asynchronous process, therefore interpreter reaches to that line.

Comment: Fix `$('#loginForm1').serialize(),`

Comment: Still getting same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, because prettyphoto clones your inline content by opening. After opening your inline content, you have to clear the original content - otherwise you've got everything twice - and if you close prettyphoto, you have to put it back there, if its not dynamic generated.
Example:
`$.fn.prettyPhoto({
     ajaxcallback:function(){
       $("#yourhiddenformid").html("");
     },
     callback:function(){
       no need, if its dynamic generated, otherwise:
       rewrite html of div;
     }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind onsubmit event on form:

```
$("#loginForm1").on('submit', function (e) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'auth_check.php',
         data: $('#loginForm1').serialize(),
         type: 'POST',
         cache: false,
         success: function (result) {
             if (result == 'success') {}
         },
         error: function (result) {}
     });
     e.preventDefault();
     $.prettyPhoto.close();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working . on submit event is not firing i tried putting alert inside function.it just refreshing page.

Comment: @user3134221, Try execute in javascript console: $('#loginForm1').length - How many length of it?

Comment: Also, how much times you include jquery?

Comment: I didnt get this question as i am new to jquery but in my file there are two places one is this pretty photo section -->  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  ...................
 });     and second is (function($){ 
 $(document).ready(function(){ ....my events..... });
})(jQuery);

Comment: Look at source of page and count how many times <script src="jquery">

Comment: @user3134221, and execute  `$('#loginForm1').length`

Comment: $('#loginForm1').length is 2

Comment: 2 times following are the lines -- >   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

Comment: 1st, You have to know Id is `UNIQUE Identificator`, well you have 2 with same id, make fix. 2nd, remove second load of jquery

Comment: thanks for reply.Well i have not used same id twice any where in my file.Also,removal of second load of jquery doesnt help.i have one more form on same page and is passing parameters only once.but this form is causing issue.

Comment: Still unable to fix it :( I have added more code to the question.please have the look

Comment: its not live..its on localhost :(

Comment: Do you have now only one LoginForm1?

Comment: Somewhere on stackoverflow.com i read that .click is not working with pretty photo hence i used .live after trying with .click .i guess issues is related to prettyphoto \